# Simple waiting for value from async thread

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, grand-central-dispatch, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I've got 2 basic methods - `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. According to my App philosophy, when view controller loads, it fetches data from base and starts to sort it with some predicates. Fetching process is long, so I dispatched it to global queue. When my view appears, it obviously do not get the value from array(which compiles in load method) and crashes. So I need  `viewDidAppear` to wait till at least one object will be appended to array.
Kind of semaphores or temp values? 
Thanks in advance!

P.S. Each item in array represent struct with data which composes UI. User interact with this UI, so it has to be loaded once with the first item from array. To switch to next item, user just clicks "next" and UI changes according to next item from array. That's why I want the data to fetch in background and allow user to work immediately. (It's impossible to jump on 5th, 10th or 1001st element immediately, there will be enough time to fetch data before user gets on these page numbers)

P.P.S Still no right decision :(

Comment: Tell, don't ask. Use an asynchronous completion block and set the data array / reload the table view in the completion block.

Comment: @vadian unfortunately it will "freeze" interface with long "progress bar" loading.

Comment: Your UI should not depend on the fetched dáta. Imagine that the Internet connection will not be available. Your UI should be responsive even in that case. Showing some placeholder or empty data until the real data are available.

Comment: @user3441734 yes, I understand it properly, but I want to make it active just after several data has bee loaded. If there is no data(no connection) it will just tell user about it

Answer (score 0):

You should using a nested dispatch block, like so:

```
func fetch(completion block:(() -> Void)?) {
    // Run fetch on background thread, to prevent the main thread (and hence your UI) from being 'blocked'.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        //
        // Fetch data...
        //

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            block?()
        })
    })
}

fetch(completion: {
    // Update your UI
})
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it, but as I understand correctly, it updates UI after each item, appended to array. I've got on the average 3000-5000 items in array. In 1 sec it can be fetched 5-10 items, so I will see 5-10 UI updates? In fact, each item represent struct with data. I compose the whole UI with data from item struct. User can interact with this data: write some text, click some triggers, so if UI will be refreshed, user can loose some work process.

Comment: In this situation, you have a choice: you can either fetch all the data first (which may take quite some time), or you can "progressively" load the UI. What I mean by this is say you have 1000 items, each of which depend on the data you are fetching. You should load a view *in its place* that is "temporary". Then, when the data has been fetched, you load the *actual* view in it's place. This way, the user can interact with UI components that depend on data that has been already fetched, while other components are still loading. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems to be the easiest way, but for some reasons waiting can last too long and user will just sit and look in progress bar. That's the problem, I want user to start work immediately

Comment: Yes I understand, which is I recommend the latter option: loading the UI progressively. For example, have a look at the new feed in the Facebook mobile app. The UI is displayed for posts that are already fetched, but if you scroll down fast enough, you'll see a "placeholder" for UI that are still waiting for data to be fetched / retrieved.

Comment: Okay, I've got a single view with several UILabels and UIImageViews. I will leave them empty till my data will be fetched? UI changes just with new labels text and images by clicking "next", so I do not see any obvious places for placeholders. Facebook uses continuous scrolling, it loads data far below and with fast internet you may not even see these placeholders

Comment: You could have "Loading..." instead, or alternatively, use something like a UIRefreshControl as a "placeholder" to indicate to the user that data is still being fetch for the respective view.